# Route internet traffic from the VM via openVPN in MacOS

Tags: linux, vpn, openvpn, macos-big-sur

My VPN allows only one connection to the VPN at a time.

*Host OS : Mac OS Big Sur*

*VM: linux on VMWare Fusion*

I wish to use the VPN on both.

I have tried adding route

`sudo route -n add -net 10.0.0.0/8 192.168.11.1`

Where 192.168.11.1 is the gateway ip of the VPN. However, this does not seem to work.

The VPN is on **utun2** while the VM is on **bridge100**.

*EDIT: Changing network adapter to NAT does not do the trick*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there is an issue with Big Sur. It does not allow through traffic.

As a temporary fix, ran the following commands:

`sudo pfctl -a com.apple.internet-sharing/shared_v4 -s nat 2>/dev/null >newrules.conf`

`echo "nat on utun2 inet from 192.168.13.0/24 to any -> (utun2) extfilter ei" >>newrules.conf`

`sudo pfctl -a com.apple.internet-sharing/shared_v4 -N -f newrules.conf 2>/dev/null`

Here `192.168.13.0/24` is the ip range where my VM is.

This needs to run every time the VM is restarted.

Comment: I know this is old but quick question.. I need to run the VPN on my host, and I need to be able to access the host machine via IP from the VM (VmWare Fusion) – will this fix that issue? Basically I'm running a webserver from the host machine (1.2.3.4:3000 for example), that web server needs to run behind the VPN. Then from the VM I need to access that webserver.

Comment: Doesn't work with "utun2". I had to pick "utun4" in my case. Can you elaborate a bit on which one is the right one? I just picked the "utun" device with the greatest number.